# WSO2 Operations Log Empty

Tags: wso2

I've installed WSO2 and have it running, devices connected (Android) etc.

I can see the device and the information about it, but the operations log is empty and it's not letting me view the installed applications or deploy new ones.

I've probably missed something basic, but I can't for the life of me see what it is, any help welcome!

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, go through the topics of the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and particularly [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I assume you have usb debugging enabled? In the Developer options, right?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are running WSO2 IoT server 3.1.0.

Please follow these steps to enable debug logs.

Go to the IOT_HOME/conf/log4j.properties file.

**Uncomment the following two**

```
#log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG
#log4j.logger.feign=DEBUG
```

**Comment the following one.**

```
log4j.category.org.apache.synapse=WARN
```

Then restart the IoT server.

This will start printing debug logs in the IoT_HOME/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log file.